# app.config in other directory

Tags: directory, app-config

A web service client (WCF) is compiled as a DLL, then comes the dll into the folder "c:\windows\assembly" ... just like I can now say that my DLL in `C:\client\client.dll.config` is expected?

It would perhaps also the possibility that the program store directly, the problem is that it starts from a SharePoint workflow that is surely not quite that simple.

It may sound silly, but the problem sounds so simple ... Unfortunately I have found so far after a while no concrete solution to Find.

EDIT:

No idea? It is the despair, I am running out of time and I have so much work to implement all this, and such a ridiculous number of hours to keep me?

I've found a lot in terms of editing files, but I will not change it I will change only the access to another directory where the file is ...

In the proxy classes, we refer only so eager ...

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute
  (Name = "_-ASD_-CAS01D0005P0000013203", 
   Namespace = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style",    
   ConfigurationName = "_ASD_CAS01D0005P000001320")
]
```

There must theoretically be possible to simply change the ...

I'm just trying to throw it somewhere in the folder of SharePoint, there is the program being started. The file is from "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv" started, but on this directory, the dll probably does not have access, because I still get the same error as if there was no config file there.

The file is from "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv" started, but on this directory, the dll probably does not have access, because I still get the same error as if there was no config file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData ("APP_CONFIG_FILE");
```

I can not find it an addictive client.dll.config, but instead the **web.config in SharePoint virtual directory** "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\Virtual Directories\80\" searches. I added the information there and it works fine!

Comment: Sorry, i have to wait. "You can accept your own answer tomorrow".